# Probability of being randomly paired in a chess tournament?

Tags: probability

There are 545 players competing in the chess tournament, and 22 of them are American. What is the probability of an American player being paired with two different Americans two days in a row?

This is for a story I'm writing. I studied this stuff years ago and forget how to solve these kinds of questions.

If anyone has the time to answer, this is also a part of my story:
The probability of Americans 1 and 2 being paired with Americans 3 and 4 on Day 1 of the tournament, and then 1 and 2 are paired together on Day 2 of the tournament?

EDIT: The pairings are uniformly at random and the pairings are specifically for day 1 and 2 of the tournament.

Comment: Do we make as many pairs as possible, uniformly at random, for each day? (Like a Swiss system?)

Comment: Chess tournaments may use different pairing systems. For example, Swiss system. Which pairing system you assume?

Comment: Note that the answer to the first question will depend on how many days the tournament lasts - unless you want the answer for Day 1 and Day 2 specifically.

Comment: How do you know that the pairing is random?

Comment: @JohnDouma From what I remember, *in days of yore*, round-1 chess tournament pairings are determined by the player's established chess rating.  Then, pairings in subsequent rounds are determined by results in previous rounds in the tournament.  So, it is reasonable to assume that chess ratings are *independent* of national origin.